# Data delete issue with nodeJS

Tags: javascript

My connection to the sql server was done. but the delete query is not executing and having a stuck at "connection was done successfully" my code is given below

```js
var mysql = require('mysql');
var dbconnect = {
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    pass: '',
    database: 'school'
}

var con = mysql.createConnection(dbconnect);
con.connect(function (error) {
    if (error) {
        console.log('connection failed');
    } else {
        console.log('connection done');
        deletedata(con);
    }

});

function deletedata(con) {
    let sqlquery = "DELETE * FROM `std_list` WHERE name='meshkat'";
    con.query=(sqlquery, function (error) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("data delete fail");
        } else {
            console.log('data delete done');
        }
    });
}
```

database table

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo in the `deletedata` function

delte `=` it is not assign value into `con.query` but function call

function should look like

```js
function deletedata(con) {
    let sqlquery = "DELETE * FROM `std_list` WHERE name='meshkat'";
    con.query(sqlquery, function (error) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("data delete fail");
        } else {
            console.log('data delete done');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you my problem was solved there was also a problem with my standard query language.

The "*" should not be allowed when already mentioned  specific column name as like "name='meshkat'"

BTW thanks a lot